# Javafx like Callback but without return

Tags: java, javafx

I'm looking for a standard Javafx or java interface (if it exists) that acts like a `Callback`, except that it does not return a value.

The standard `Callback` from `javafx.util` package is as follows:

```
public interface Callback<P,R> {
    public R call(P param);
}
```

This is useful when you need to return the value, but I don't. I've looked into `Callable<T>`:

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    V call() throws Exception;
}
```

But this doesn't actually pass in a value into `call`. What I'm looking for is basically this:

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    void call(V value) throws Exception;
}
```

Is there a standard Java interface, or should I just create my own?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you looking for is `Consumer`. That's added since `java 8`.

> Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result. Unlike most other functional interfaces, Consumer is expected to operate via side-effects.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Consumer<T> {

/**
 * Performs this operation on the given argument.
 *
 * @param t the input argument
 */
void accept(T t);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Runnable.run()` may be another solution like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71563433/1915920), but the `Consumer` actually does not handle `Exception` like `Callable` ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71563433/1915920)).

I could not find a standard interface supporting `Exception` and thus maybe one has to create such standard interfaces himself, like with some `interface Code` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71563433/1915920).